# How can I change the photo used for iOS8 Family Sharing?

Tags: ios, family-sharing

When setting up *Family Sharing* on iOS8, I can set up a photo for my family user (the same photo will be used for the iCloud account) by going to *Settings > iCloud > Family Sharing*. The dialog allows me to select a photo, move it, resize it.

Once I have selected and confirmed the photo I want to use, is there a way to change the photo again? Holding a finger on the photo doesn't have any effect. I haven't found a way to reset or change the photo.

Is that something that Apple has not thought about, or am I simply missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings > iCloud > tap the You line at the top > Edit > edit (under photo)

Comment: Excellent - thanks! I had to enter my iCloud password before seeing my profile and being able to edit it.

Answer (score 1):

The picture that you have in your family sharing is the picture that each family member chooses as the "me" in their contact information.  If you have Facebook on your contact information it may use your Facebook profile picture unless you edit it to another picture.  To set your "me" on iPhone or iPod touch go to Settings>Mail,Contacts,Calendars>My Info(under Contacts) and choose the contact to represent you.  Any time you go into that particular contact and edit the picture it will change the picture for you on the family sharing.  The same is true for any other family member.